# Waypoint throwing problem when using agm-direction Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I am using agm direction and I am getting this problem in visual studio code:

```
Type '{ location: { lat: number; lng: number; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'DirectionsWaypoint[]'.
  Type '{ location: { lat: number; lng: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'DirectionsWaypoint'.
    Types of property 'location' are incompatible.
      Type '{ lat: number; lng: number; }' is not assignable to type 'string | Place | LatLng'.
        Type '{ lat: number; lng: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'LatLng': equals, toUrlValue, toJSON
```

The waypoints still show and it works, but my uptight personality does not enjoy seeing a red underline, I am not sure how to get rid of it, any help would be much appreciated.

Code in typescript file:

```
waypoints = [
    {location: { lat: -25.913330, lng: 28.185640 }},
    {location: { lat: -25.869650, lng: 28.217950 }}
  ];
```

Code in html file:

```
<agm-direction [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination" [waypoints]="waypoints"></agm-direction>
```

The error appears under `[waypoints]`

Comment: Only for your information. AGM is deprecated. You could consider moving to: @angular/google-maps

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/README.md

Comment: Ahh that's a pity. I'll look into that, AGM was the only way I could get google maps working. Thanks for the heads up though really appreciate it!